# Adding an Image to a Panel in C#

Tags: c#, image, panel

I am trying to add an image of a music note to an already existing panel. I have created the  path for the image:

```
String NoteImage_path = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\Notes-Images\";
```

I tried adding the image to the panel by using the following line of code:

```
this.panel2.Controls.Add(this.NoteImage_path);
```

But I cannot convert a String to System.Windows.Form.Control.

How can I go about this problem? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to add one note, or will many notes be added to the same panel?

Comment: @Idle_Mind I want to add many notes to the panel. Unfortunately, with PictureBox I can only add 1 note.

Comment: You can add add as many PBs to the Panel as you want.   Just size and position then.   Consider a FlowLayoutPanel, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Set the background image of the panel

```
panel2.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(NoteImage_path);
```